# use db without requiring app.app_context()- Flask

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have an app like this:

myapp/app/**init**.py:

```
import sqlite3
from contextlib import closing

from flask import Flask, g
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_login import LoginManager

# from app.models import db
from database import db

application = Flask(__name__)
application.config.from_object('config')
application.debug = True

db.init_app(application)

login_manager = LoginManager()
login_manager.init_app(application)

from app import views
```

myapp/database.py:

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

db = SQLAlchemy()
```

myapp/app/models.py:

```
from database import db
from app import application


class CRUDMixin(object):

    ...

    def delete(self, commit=True):
        """Remove the record from the database."""
        with application.app_context():
            db.session.delete(self)
            return commit and db.session.commit()


class Model(CRUDMixin, db.Model):
    """Base model class that includes CRUD convenience methods."""
    __abstract__ = True

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        db.Model.__init__(self, **kwargs)


class User(Model):
    """
    :param str email: email address of user
    :param str password: encrypted password for the user
    """
    __tablename__ = 'users'

    email = db.Column(db.String, primary_key=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String)
    authenticated = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False)

    def is_active(self):
        """True, as all users are active."""
        return True

    def get_id(self):
        """Return the email address to satisfy Flask-Login's requirements."""
        return self.email

    def is_authenticated(self):
        """Return True if the user is authenticated."""
        return self.authenticated

    def is_anonymous(self):
        """False, as anonymous users aren't supported."""
        return False
```

The project I tried to structure after did not require `with application.app_context()` in the `Model` helper class. I cannot see any significant differences between my setup and its, and yet without `with application.app_context()` all over anything related to `db` I get the usual `application not registered on db` error. When everything you see in `app/models.py` and `database.py` was in `app/__init__.py`, it worked without requiring any `with application.app_context()` and I could import `db` raw in the shell like `from myapp.app import db` and it worked as is. What can I do to quiet the `application not registered on db` complaint but be able to use `db` easily without needing `app_context`, but still keep a proper directory structure where everything isn't jammed into `init`? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

`Flask-Script` gives you a [shell](http://flask-script.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#shell).

If you want to do it without `Flask-Script`, you must set the application context. A normal Python shell doesn't know how to setup your context.

It is easy to mimic the `Flask-Script` shell.

Create a `shell.py` file:

```
from app import application
ctx = application.app_context()
ctx.push()
```

Run it with `python -i` and use `db` with your app context already defined:

```
$ python -i shell.py 
>>> from app import db
>>> db.create_all()
```